# RabbitMq Client Integration With Google App Engine (PHP) (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, rabbitmq

### AMQPRuntimeException

> I am running a php application using Codeigniter and successfully uploaded to Google App Engine & Running ..
>
> I am facing issue while integrating RabbitMq client library,
>   It's working fine on local system after deploying it's not!
>
> And after using try..catch i found..

```
  PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException Object ( [message:protected] => Error Connecting to server(0): [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => /base/data/home/apps/s~pge-2015/1.382317962180174380/website/application/third_party/PhpAmqpLib/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php [line:protected] => 27 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => /base/data/home/apps/s~pge-2015/1.382317962180174380/website/application/third_party/PhpAmqpLib/vendor/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AMQPStreamConnection.php [line] => 21 [function] => __construct [class] => PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO [type] => -> [args] => Array
```

> Any Idea Why It is giving??
>
> What Is The Solution??

Comment: Apparently it's a connection error - RabbitMq library cannot connect to the server.

Comment: You mean to say, Am able to create socket connection at local system but  When i deploy it to GAE Server it's unable to create socket connection ??

Comment: Exactly. Here's the place where the exception is thrown: https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/blob/master/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php#L106

Comment: Yes i saw that StreamIO file..
I guess i should raise issue ..

Comment: Is your app bill enabled? "Sockets are only available for paid apps" https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/sockets/

Comment: Yes... and i am using different credentials not using GAE will be any problems ??? but i can access web console for rabbitmq using that creds

Comment: @Mars you were right only paid apps can work with socket operations